# What is the difference between $\sqrt{x^2}$ and $(\sqrt{x})^2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$\sqrt{x^2}\;$ and $(\sqrt{x})^2$;
I mean, are they equal? because 
what about the following facts:
$\sqrt{x^2} = (x^2)^{1/2} = x^{(2)(\frac{1}{2})} = x^{\frac{2}{2}} = x \\
(\sqrt{x})^2 = x^{\frac{1}{2}(2)}= x^{(\frac{1}{2})(2)} = x^{\frac{2}{2}} = x$

Comment: Set $x = -1$. Are they the same?

Comment: I do not know, which operation I have to do first power or root?

Comment: $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$ and $(\sqrt{x})^2=x$. Now read again @T.Bongers's comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As functions over the reals,
the domain of $\sqrt {x^2}$ is $\mathbb R$,
the domain of ${\sqrt x}^2$ is $[0,\infty)$.

Verbally, in the same order,
the square root of (x squared),
the square of (square root of x).

Does that clarify the order?

Comment: but what about the following fact:
${x^{(1/2)}}^2  = x^{2/2} = x$
$x^{2}^{1/2} = x^{2/2} = x $

Comment: @JoséMarín:  MathJax hint:  for multicharacter exponents, enclose them in braces, so x^{(1/2)} gives $x^{(1/2)}$.  It works everywhere.

Comment: For the first fact the range of x has to be complex numbers.

Comment: I see now! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The point is that in the first you square and then take the square root.  That works well even if $x$ is negative.  The second has you take the square root first, which you can't do if $x$ is negative, then square the result.  As long as $x$ is positive the two are equal, but if $x$ is negative the second is undefined. 
 The point of the question is the order of operations.